# How to load certain amount of objects per page?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I want in a table view to load a certain amount of objects per page. Like what Instagram does. I've only seen how to do this in a PFQueryTableViewController using the line of code...

```
self.objectsPerPage = //Amount of objects per page
```

I am using Parse but I'm not using a PFQueryTableViewController. How would I accomplish the same thing the line of code above does?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to load a limited amount of data in parse, but the way I do it is by loading 5 posts, and then loading more posts when the `scrollViewDidScroll(view: UIScrollView)` function is called, and `view.contentOffset.y + view.frame.size.height >= view.contentSize.height`. Essentially, this loads more posts whenever the user scrolls to the bottom of the view.

Comment: did it solve the problem? have you tried downloading 100 post and storing it to an array and just controlling the objects to show everytime u scroll down?

Comment: @Jojodmo I understand how to do it but could you show me how to do it in code because I'm pretty new to Swift and not sure how I would do that.

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh, in that case I'm not sure, because I'm not familiar with parse.

Comment: @Jojodmo Ok no problem! Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Try approaching it this way

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y < (view.bounds.size.height) {
        if !isLoading() {
            loadNextPage()
        }
    }
}
```

loading the next objects when the tableview is within full screen, play around.

source : [Detecting the bottom "bounce" of UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18191686/detecting-the-bottom-bounce-of-uitableview)

Edit : you can use this pod as well

https://cocoapods.org/pods/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll

Comment: How would I do the loadNextPage function?